# Customize SharePoint Online Modern Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, modern-experience

We need to customize the SharePoint Online Modern search results. Is there any approach to customize the modern SharePoint search results.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your requirement?

Comment: I want to customize the SharePoint modern search results as like classic search results. Is it possible?

Comment: If any of the below answers are satisfying your question then, please accept it so it will help the other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not customize the search results as we used to do in the classic search result page as mentioned [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Is-there-any-option-to-create-search-results-page-in-modern-team/m-p/271316). However, you can use the PnP Modern Search web part as described in this post [SharePoint Online – Search Options Today](https://searchexplained.com/sharepoint-online-search-options-2019-july/).

You can find the details about Pnp Modern Search from the below link.

[PnP Modern Search solution](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/)

Comment: For now we can use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

We can't customize the SharePoint Online Modern search results.

The modern search experience only shows results from the default result source. If you change the default result source, both search experiences are impacted.

[Differences between the classic and modern search experiences in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/differences-classic-modern-search)

You can try the method mentioned by dhruvil.

Answer (score 0):

That capability is coming to Office 365 and should be rolled out in 2020. It was detailed in a session at Ignite.

**What's new and next for Microsoft Search customization and development**
https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/85238?source=sessions

Comment: Needless to say this should have been done before modern was rolled out at all. An intranet without configurable search isn't "modern" at all.

Comment: @matt You are preaching to the choir!

Comment: The link is no longer available. Could you provide another page with similar content?